# Does anyone have an open data source on opinions about the replication (reproducibility) crisis in science?

Tags: survey

I asked a question on the [Academia Stack Exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/125172/survey-data-on-scientists-opinions-on-reproducibility-replication-crisis-espec) about surveys of scientists asking their opinions on the replication crisis (also called the reproducibility crisis). It was suggested to me there that asking the question here might find something. So here goes!

I am specifically looking for survey data covering the replication or reproducibility crisis as it appears in various fields of science. I am aware of the general survey of scientists published in [Nature](https://www.nature.com/news/1-500-scientists-lift-the-lid-on-reproducibility-1.19970).

What I am looking for are any additional surveys for other specific fields/areas of scientific research. While I have found other types of studies, those do not give me the opinions of the working scientists themselves. Opinions are what I am looking for right now.

I am particularly interested in a survey covering the field of psychology. This field has produced a lot of work related to this topic: articles on research methodologies, questionable research practices, statistical issues, and so on, but little that I can find on the opinion of the psychological researchers themselves.

Are there any surveys?